# C# Access insert query not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Okay so this code produces no errors but doesn't add the data to the database. When a button is pressed, it should insert all values in the text boxes into the database.

```
private void addSportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

  for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++){

    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(CONNECTION STRING HERE);
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TotalPlayerName ([PlayerName]) VALUES (@name)";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.Connection = connection;
    connection.Open();
    command.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = textBox[i].Text;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

changed some things around in previous sections of code and now there are rows added but nothing appears in the PlayerName field

Code for creating the text boxes

```
        for (int t = 0; t < 18; t++)
         {

             textBox[t] = new TextBox(); 

             this.Controls.Add(textBox[t]);
             this.textBox[t].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));

            // if it is the first text box then it must go in this location
             if (t == 0)
             {

                textBox[t].Location = new Point(32, 41);
                textBox[t].Visible = true;


             }
            else
             {
                 // every other text box will be 27px below the previous
                textBox[t].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(32, 41 + (t * 27));
                textBox[t].Visible = false;


             }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure about errors? Insert code in `try-catch` block

Comment: what should I add into each part? and as for the parameters, surely there is one parameter every time it loops trough the for loop?

Comment: So the code is definitely running, ie numberOfPlayers is greater than zero and you can step through in the debugger?

Comment: yeah the code works fine

Comment: Do you have your ACCDB/MDB file listed between your project files? If yes click on it and look at the value of the property `Copy To The Output directory`. What is its value?

Comment: what do you mean by listed between project files? as in the same directory as the project?

Comment: In your project/solution window in Visual Studio, between the .cs files do you have also the ACCDB/MDB file?

Comment: The database is in a seperate directory completely, could this be the issue?

Comment: Then change this line _int rowsAdded = command.ExecuteNonQuery(); MessageBox.Show("Added " + rowsAdded + " row");_ What do you get as value for rowsAdded?

Comment: it says that 1 row was added

Comment: So the code works, just it adds records not to the database that you think is using. What is the ConnectionString value?

Comment: Okay now I have noticed that the row is added but there is no value in the PlayerName field - i.e. the value in textBox[i]

Comment: How do you build the textbox[] array?

Comment: I create the array of text box controls within the code, I can show you this code if you like?

Comment: If you use the debugger you could look at what values are present in the array. Something is not apparent here. Yes please add the code that initializes the array.

Comment: Ditto my comments from this thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34500273/insert-into-c-sharp-to-microsoft-access/34500843#34500843

Comment: I have edited the question to include the code I use to create the text boxes

Comment: Well, I am sorry but I have no more ideas. This should work, provided that you have set something in the textboxes. Whitout looking at the Whole project database included it is not possible for me to understand what's happening here. If you are willing to share your code you could post a zip file on some sharing site and post the link here. I will take a look at it time permitting

Answer (score 2):

Nine times out of ten, when an insert 'fails' and there is no error message....you are looking in the wrong database.

You are inserting to database 'A'

But looking for the record in database 'B'

Comment: Ah! this was exactly what happened to me. In my case I provided a relative path and it was pointing to a mdb file in bin/debug where as I was looking for the inserted record in my main project folder, scratching my head. Awesome. thanks Steve.